# I need to upload an object to the google drive and parse the link to a google sheet

Tags: node.js, typescript, forms, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I developed a form using nextjs,

```
    import { useState } from "react";
import Step1 from "../components/step/step-1";
import Step2 from "../components/step/step-2";
import Step3 from "../components/step/step-3";
import Step4 from "../components/step/step-4";
import Step5 from "../components/step/step-5";

export default function V2() {


  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    yearClass: "",
    admissionNo: "",
    applicationDate: "",
    applicantPhoto: null,
    guardian1Type: "",
    guardian1Name: "",
    guardian1DateOfBirth: "",
    guardian1Occupation: "",
    guardian1AddressPhone: "",
    guardian1Signature: null,
    guardian2Type: "",
    guardian2Name: "",
    guardian2DateOfBirth: "",
    guardian2Occupation: "",
    guardian2AddressPhone: "",
    guardianEmail: "",
    guardianIsAlumnus: "",
    guardianAttendanceDate: "",
    guardian2Signature: null,
    guardianIncome: "",
    applicantNeedStatement: "",
    needSignature: null,
    reference1Name: "",
    reference1Relationship: "",
    reference1Occupation: "",
    reference1Address: "",
    reference1PhoneNumber: "",
    reference1Email: "",
    reference1Letter: "",
    reference1Signature: null,
    reference2Name: "",
    reference2Relationship: "",
    reference2Occupation: "",
    reference2Address: "",
    reference2PhoneNumber: "",
    reference2Email: "",
    reference2Letter: "",
    reference2Signature: null,
    academicAwards: "",
    prizeExtra: "",
    commendation: "",
    transcriptHistory: null,
  });

  

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formDataToSend = new FormData();

    // console.log("data",formData);

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(formData)) {
      formDataToSend.append(key, value);
      if (
        key === "applicantPhoto"
      )
      console.log(value);
    }



    const uploadResponse = await fetch("/api/upload",{
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    console.log("data succesfully processed", uploadResponse);




    const response = await fetch("/api/submit", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    console.log(await response.json());
  };

   
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handlePhotoChange = (event) => {
    const { name, files } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: files[0],
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <div className="container"> */}
      <div className="wrapper clearfix">
        {/* for rtl */}
        {/* <div className="wrapper clearfix" dir='rtl'> */}

        <div className="wizard-part-title">
          <h3>Saint Finbarr's College Scholarship</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="multisteps-form">
          {/* <div className="container"> */}

          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-12 mx-auto">
              <div className="multisteps-form__progress">
                <button className="multisteps-form__progress-btn js-active">
                  Applicant Data
                </button>
                <button className="multisteps-form__progress-btn">
                  Parent/Guardian's
                </button>
                <button className="multisteps-form__progress-btn">
                  Financial Need
                </button>
                <button className="multisteps-form__progress-btn">
                  References
                </button>
                <button className="multisteps-form__progress-btn">
                  Miscellaneous
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* </div> */}
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12 col-lg-12 m-auto">
            <form
              className="multisteps-form__form clearfix"
              action="#"
              method="post"
              id="wizard"
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
              <Step1
                formData={formData}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                handlePhotoChange={handlePhotoChange}
              />
              <Step2
                formData={formData}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                handlePhotoChange={handlePhotoChange}
              />
              <Step3
                formData={formData}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                handlePhotoChange={handlePhotoChange}
              />
              <Step4
                formData={formData}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                handlePhotoChange={handlePhotoChange}
              />
              <Step5
                formData={formData}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                handlePhotoChange={handlePhotoChange}
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* </div> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

that using two Api, the first api, collect object(files/image) and submit it to google drive and return the file link

```
// import multer from "multer";

// const ALLOWED_FORMATS = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"];

// const maxSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB

// const storage = multer.diskStorage({
//   destination: (_req, _file, callback) => {
//     // @ts-ignore
//     callback(null, __dirname + "/_temp");
//   },
//   filename: (_req, file, callback) => {
//     callback(null, file.originalname);
//   },
// });
// const upload = multer({
//   storage,
//   limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
//   fileFilter: function (
//     _req: Request,
//     file,
//     cb: (arg0: any, arg1: any) => void
//   ) {
//     if (ALLOWED_FORMATS.includes(file.mimetype)) {
//       cb(null, true);
//     } else {
//       cb(new Error("Not supported file type!"), false);
//     }
//   },
// });

// export const singleUploadCtrl = (fieldname: string) => {
//   const singleUpload = upload.single(fieldname);
//   return (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
//     singleUpload(req, res, (error) => {
//       if (error) {
//         return 'error';
//         // return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Files uploaded successfully.', fileLinks });
//       }

//       next();
//     });
//   };
// };


// import { google } from 'googleapis';
// import formidable from 'formidable';

// export default async function handler(req, res) {
//   if (req.method === 'POST') {
//     try {
//       const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
//       form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
//         if (err) {
//           res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error parsing form data.' });
//           return;
//         }

//         // Authenticate with Google API using your credentials
//         const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
//           keyFile: 'key/sfcobana-91b709ad1e42.json',
//           scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
//         });
//         const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

//         const fileLinks = [];

//         // Loop through each file and upload it to Google Drive
//         for (const fileKey in files) {
//           const file = files[fileKey];
//           const resDrive = await drive.files.create({
//             requestBody: {
//               name: file.name,
//               mimeType: file.type,
//             },
//             media: {
//               mimeType: file.type,
//               body: file.path,
//             },
//           });

//           // Get the web link of the uploaded file
//           const fileLink = resDrive.data.webViewLink;
//           fileLinks.push({ name: file.name, link: fileLink });
//         }

//         res.status(200).json({ message: 'Files uploaded successfully.', fileLinks });
//       });
//     } catch (error) {
//       console.error('Error uploading files:', error);
//       res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading files.' });
//     }
//   } else {
//     res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not allowed.' });
//   }
// }
import { google } from "googleapis";
import multer from "multer";
import fs from "fs";

const upload = multer({ dest: "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T-0sb5EBSk0RY5sxTEDyxHGhOYyJJuoT/" }); 

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      upload.single("applicantPhoto")(req, res, async (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json({ error: "Error uploading files." });
          return;
        }

        // Authenticate with Google API using your credentials
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
          keyFile: "key/sfcobana-91b709ad1e42.json",
          scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
        });
        const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

        const fileLinks = [];

        console.log("body",req.body);
        console.log(req.file);
        console.log("files ",req.files);

        // Loop through each file and upload it to Google Drive
        // for (const file of req.files) {
        //   try {
        //     const resDrive = await drive.files.create({
        //       requestBody: {
        //         name: file.originalname,
        //         mimeType: file.mimetype,
        //       },
        //       media: {
        //         mimeType: file.mimetype,
        //         body: fs.createReadStream(file.path),
        //       },
        //     });

        //     // Get the web link of the uploaded file
        //     const fileLink = resDrive.data.webViewLink;
        //     fileLinks.push({ name: file.originalname, link: fileLink });
        //   } catch (error) {
        //     console.error("Error uploading file:", file.originalname);
        //     console.error(error);
        //   } finally {
        //     // Delete the temporary file after uploading to Google Drive
        //     fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
        //   }
        // }

        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ message: "Files uploaded successfully.", fileLinks });
          console.log("file links", fileLinks);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading files:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Error uploading files." });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Method not allowed." });
  }
}
```

and the second submit the all data including the file links to a google sheet,

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

type SheetForm = {

      name: string,
      email: string,
      dateOfBirth: string,
      yearClass: string,
      admissionNo: string,
      applicationDate: string,
      applicantPhoto: string,
      guardian1Type: string,
      guardian1Name: string,
      guardian1DateOfBirth: string,
      guardian1Occupation: string,
      guardian1AddressPhone: string,
      guardian1Signature: Object,
      guardian2Type: string,
      guardian2Name: string,
      guardian2DateOfBirth: string,
      guardian2Occupation: string,
      guardian2AddressPhone: string,
      guardianEmail: string,
      guardianIsAlumnus: string,
      guardianAttendanceDate: string,
      guardian2Signature: Object,
      guardianIncome: string,
      applicantNeedStatement: string,
      needSignature: Object,
      reference1Name: string,
      reference1Relationship: string,
      reference1Occupation: string,
      reference1Address: string,
      reference1PhoneNumber: string,
      reference1PhoneEmail: string,
      reference1Letter: string,
      reference1Signature: Object,
      reference2Name: string,
      reference2Relationship: string,
      reference2Occupation: string,
      reference2Address: string,
      reference2PhoneNumber: string,
      reference2PhoneEmail: string,
      reference2Letter: string,
      reference2Signature: Object,
      academicAwards: string,
      prizeExtra: string,
      commendation: string,
      transcriptHistory: string,
}

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

      if (req.method !== "POST") {
            return res.status(405).send({ message: "Only Post request are allowed" })
      }


      const body = req.body as SheetForm

      try {

            // prepare auth credentials
            const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
                  credentials: {
                        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                        client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
                        private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
                  },

                  scopes: [
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
                  ]
            });

            const sheet = google.sheets({
                  auth,
                  version: 'v4'
            })

            const values = [
                  Object.values(body)
            ]

            // Check for empty or undefined values
            // if (values.flat().some((value) => value === undefined || value === null)) {
            //       return res.status(400).json({ message: "Form data contains empty or undefined values" });
            // }

            // Convert numbers to strings
            const stringValues = values.map(row => row.map(value => String(value)));


            const response = await sheet.spreadsheets.values.append({
                  spreadsheetId: process.env.GOOGLE_SHEET_ID,
                  range: "Sheet1!A2:A",
                  valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
                  requestBody: {
                        values: stringValues
                  }
            })

            return res.status(200).json({
                  data: response.data,
                  message: 'Form submitted successfully',
                  values: Object.values(req.body)
            })

            // //send smtp 
            // const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
            // //create transporter object using your email
            // const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            //       service: 'mail.google.com',
            //       auth:{
            //             user: 'webtest@sfcobanorthamerica.org',
            //             pass: 'Miracle@6',
            //       },
            // });

            // //to send the email
            // const sendEmail = async (formData) => {
            //       try {
            //             //compose the email message
            //             const message = {
            //                   from: 'webtest@sfcobanorthamerica.org',
            //                   to: ['schorlarship@sfcobanorthamerica.org',formData.email],
            //                   subject: 'SFCO Application Form',
            //                   Text: `A new form has been submittted with the following data:\n\n${JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2)}`,
            //             };
            //       }
            // }

      } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).send({ message: error.message ?? 'Something went wrong' })

      }

}
```

but the issue now is that the code is submitting the values to sheet, but the object is not submitting to the drive and not even generation a file link, is given undefined.

Comment: First, it looks like you've included your entire code. Most people won't have time to go through that amount of code. You need to include just the relevant bit and folks can ask for more if they need it. Secondly, you said the google sheet isn't being submitted to the drive. If so, what error do you get? Show just the part of the code that tries to save the file to the drive or the part that you believe has the error